# What does "taking the adjoint" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, adjoint-functors

In the **Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology** by **Davis & Kirk**, we consider the **Kronecker pairing** which is defined by

$$H^n(C;R) \times H_n(C;R) \to R \\ ([\varphi],[\alpha]) \mapsto \varphi(\alpha)$$

where $H^n(C;R)$ is the cohomology and $H_n(C;R)$ is the homology with coefficients over a ring $R$.

Then it is said

> Deduce by *taking the adjoints* that the Kronecker pairing defines a map $$H^n(C;R) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C;R),R).$$

I assume that this map is defined by $[\varphi] \mapsto ([\alpha] \mapsto \varphi(\alpha))$.

***My question***: What exactly does "taking the adjoints" mean? Does it has something to do with adjoint functors? Or maybe with the Adjoint Property of Tensor Products which is the following result

> **Proposition 1.14** (Adjoint Property of Tensor Products) *There is an isomorphism of $R$-modules $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(A \otimes_R B, C) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_R(A, \operatorname{Hom}_R(B,C))$$ natural in $A$, $B$, $C$ given by* $\phi \leftrightarrow (a \mapsto (b \mapsto \phi(a \otimes b) ) ).$

It might be obvious but I just don't see it. I am thankful for any explanation!

Comment: Yeah, that is precisely it. A bilinear map is actually a linear map from the tensor product. And then the adjoint property of tensor products immediately gives you the map as said.

Comment: Note that the adjoint property of the tensor product *is* a specific case of adjoint functors : it implies that the functor $\_\otimes_RB $ is the left adjoint of the functor $Hom_R(B,\_)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, "taking the adjoint" means the following two steps. (1) By the universal property of the tensor product, view the Kronecker pairing as a homomorphism $H^n\otimes H_n\to R$. (2) Apply the adjoint property that you quoted to convert this homomorphism to a homomorphism $H^n\to\text{Hom}(H_n,R)$.  Strictly speaking, "taking the adjoint" seems to refer to (2), but apparently (1) is to be understood.  I suppose the author viewed (1) as so evident that it didn't need to be mentioned separately.